# How to use DI when spawning new Windows Forms downstream?

Tags: c#, winforms, dependency-injection, unity-container

I have the Unity DI container working *initially* with my Windows Forms application. In `Program.cs` I have the following:

```
static void Main()
{
    var container = BuildUnityContainer();
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    Application.Run(container.Resolve<MainForm>());
}

private static IUnityContainer BuildUnityContainer()
{
    var container = new UnityContainer();
    container.RegisterType<ITest, MyTestClass>();
    container.RegisterType<ISomeOtherTest, MyOtherClass>();
    return container;
}
```

In my `MainForm` constructor I have the following **which does work**:

```
private readonly ITest test;

        public MainForm(ITest test)
        {
            this.test = test;
            InitializeComponent();
        }
```

The container is resolved and the code works fine. The problem / question is, how do I instantiate a new form from `MainForm`, say `Form2` that has the following constructor:

```
private readonly ISomeOtherTest someOtherTest;

    public Form2(ISomeOtherTest someOtherTest)
    {
       this.someOtherTest = someOtherTest;
       InitializeComponent();
    }
```

If I try the following in my `MainForm`:

```
Form2 form2 = new Form2();
form2.Show();
```

It will break, complaining that I have not supplied the values to the constructor. However I have already resolved my container and I thought all downstream containers would be resolved. Obviously I'm missing something here though as it does not work.

Does this mean I have to front load *all* dependencies into `MainForm` even if that form does not use it so I can then pass them to any new form instantiations I make? The would be weird if I had 50 dependencies to resolve and had the constructor for the top level form take them all. Please help clear up my understanding as I have used Unity and DI containers almost exclusively in Web API and MVC which already has the DI resolver built in for the Controllers, so I must be missing some pieces and understanding here.

Comment: DI works well with ASP.NET because the object creation is delegated through a pipeline and they put themselves in there. In WinForm / WPF you need to create that type through your container, most of the time. Also, if you need more help, you should at least tell which DI you are using (Unity, Ninject, etc..)

Comment: @SimonBelanger - Read the 4th word in my post please: "I have the *Unity* DI..." And again it is stated in my last paragraph: "I have used *Unity*..." You read too fast, and providing examples instead of abstract descriptions is more helpful here please.

Comment: @atconway, excellently stated question. I'm struggling with this exact same problem myself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should create your form like so

```
Form2 form = container.Resolve<Form2>();
```

You were not using the container, therefore the Form does not have a constructor which takes no arguments. If you resolve it with the container, it will examine the constructor, find the dependencies and automatically inject them into the constructor for you.

So.. maybe your problem is that you do not have access to the container in your MainForm? If this is the problem there are two approaches..

**Inject IUnityContainer into MainForm constructor**

However... people who live by the "composition root" pattern will tell you that you should only use the container from the root of your application (in this case, probably Main() ) The other option is...

**Create a Form2 factory class from your composition root (Main) which gets injected into MainForm and MainForm uses the factory to create Form2**

You should read more into the Composition Root theory of thinking...

[Composition Root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/)

---

update

I've never had to do it before, but I think the second method would look something like this...

```
public class Form2Factory : IForm2Factory
{
    private readonly ISomeOtherTest someOtherTest;

    public Form2Factory(ISomeOtherTest someOtherTest)
    {
        this.someOtherTest = someOtherTest;
    }

    public Form2 Create()
    {
        return new Form2(someOtherTest);
    }
}


public class MainForm
{
    private readonly IForm2Factory form2Factory;

    public MainForm(IForm2Factory form2Factory)
    {
        this.form2Factory = form2Factory;
    }

    private void DoingSomething()
    {
        Form2 form = form2Factory.Create();
        form.Show();
    }
}
```

Comment: How do I get access to that `container` variable in my `MainForm` please? That was declared only locally in `Program.cs`, and I do not see it in Intellisense. Should I have passed it along somehow?

Comment: @atconway: Declare `container` as public.

Comment: I would have to declare it as `public static IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();` since `Program.cs` is a `static` class. Is this the proper way to do this?

Comment: Then I have to call it through the `static` class name like `Form2 form = Program.container.Resolve<Form2>();` Is this also correct?

Comment: @Alan - Actually after reading the comments only and following through I re-read your statement: *"Create a Form2 factory class from your composition root (Main) which gets injected into MainForm and MainForm uses the factory to create Form2"* This sounds probably like what I want to do. I read that link and some of the links it spawned, but didn't see an example exactly to this. Do you have a sample of using a Factory for the `Form2`, and how this would work even further downstream to `Form3`, `Form4`, `Form5`, etc. The 'global' method suggested above *does actually work*; just not sure.

Comment: @atconway You know, I wasnt' sure myself. I had the same question. But, I thought about it a bit more and read some of Mark Seeman's answers on stackoverflow. I updated my answer with an idea on how it can be done. In this case, you do not need to create the factory yourself. The MainForm resolve will automatically inject the factory into MainForm. I believe that is sorta the idea with composition root (A single resolve call to the container).

Comment: @atconway Oh... one more thing please don't make use of your container as a static variable. You might as well be using a ServiceLocator at that point. http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/

Comment: @Alan -Thanks for the help on this. One question with the factory being injected into `MainForm`. Is this back to where I have to inject every single factory for all forms spawned downstream? Meaning the signature might look like: `public MainForm(IForm2Factory form2Factory, IForm3Factory form3Factory, IForm4Factory form4Factory, IForm5Factory form6Factory, IForm6Factory form2Factory)` ? Or is there another way later to resolve, or am I missing something?

Comment: @atconway Yeah, these are good questions. I think at some point you need to determine what is reasonable and how it affects separation of concerns and testing. Are you testing your Forms? Or are you testing your business logic? But I agree with you, I dunno how the Composition Root theory deals with that case. Also, I am writing a modular application and in my case at least each module needs to interact with the container. One idea might be if all your Forms require 1-2 dependencies is to inject those dependencies, and call new on the forms inside MainForm with those dependencies in the ctor

Comment: @alan, If you inject a full fledged `FormFactory` into your `MainForm`, that's not very different from actually injecting (a somewhat restricted version of) the `container` itself, only more abstract.

Comment: @MEMark Well the FormFactory can return an interface to a form.. that perhaps would allow you to Mock that form (and factory) and test the parent and child form independently? I think the difference is, if you were testing one of these classes, do you want to pass it a container? or a FormFactory? which is better? I would think the latter

Comment: @alan, that's actually a good point. It's easy to sometimes forget WHY you wan't to use DI. Being able to unit test a form in isolation is indeed a good reason. One thing still troubles me though. If my sub form needs a dependency, how do I resolve it? By requesting this dependecy in the FormFactory constructor and manually providing it? It's sad if I'm not able to use my DI container at all in creating these sub forms.

Comment: @MEMark All your business logic and functionality should basically be in your ViewModels, I think 99% of people who are testing aren't testing (automated) their UIs. Microsoft, sure..