# Proper implementation of factory pattern using DI

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns, dependency-injection, factory

I've got a question about the cleanest way for constructing new instances of some abstraction in a factory using Dependency Injection. The thing is that I use some presenter which opens it's views multiple times, but when we only "close" some view, it's being disposed, and to open the view again I need to get a new View instance once again and then I can open it.

For now the "factory" looks like this:

```
class ViewConstructor<TView> :IViewConstructor<TView>
    where TView : class, IView
{
    private readonly IIocContainer _iocContainer;

    public ViewConstructor(IIocContainer iocContainer)
    {
        _iocContainer = iocContainer;
    }

    public TView Construct()
    {
        return _iocContainer.GetInstance<TView>();
    }
}
```

The thing is, that I know that using IocContainer anywhere but not in the composition root it a bad thing. So I'm guessing if there's some "clean" way to implement this. To sum up, i want to be able to get **MULTIPLE** instances of the IView from the factory.

Comment: Do `TView`s use CTOR-Injection? As far as I can see here, _I_'d probably just do `new WhateverConcreteViewINeed(this);` instead of using that factory?

Comment: Yes, every IView is also registered in  DI Container, every of the IView has multiple-dependency constructors. So creating an instance of the IView using "new" would make more problems to me, that i have right now ;)

Comment: Maybe add an example of such an IView impl. to make this a little clearer. And also your DI config (the relevant parts).

Comment: Unfortunately I cant provide code of the IView, anyway it's just an another dependency that uses CTOR-injection as well. To create a wider view, i can tell that at the very beginning i injected the IView directly to the presenter. Everything was fine until requirements changed. Now, presenter has to have ability to run views multiple times - and it also has to take care about disposing the IViews properly. Running the IView by the presente looks like `using(var view = _viewConstructor.Construct()) { view.Run(); }`

Comment: I see. So you are pretty much pinned to that corner here. But why do you stress that you want to be able to resolve _multiple_ instances? That should be a matter of how you register the type with your DI Framework, right?

Comment: The thing is, that shredded calls to `_iocContainer.GetInstance` are not good for eg. testing. It makes tests of ViewContructor much complicated that it should be. The only thing i want to know, is if there's some pattern or BETTER way to solve the case, when i would need MULTIPLE instances of some dependency in a single presenter. Apart from the mentioned issues, the code works just fine and does what it has to do.

Comment: This seems like something you would generally solve using scoping. That is: you let the container or the factory cache resolved views and at one point let the application signal that all resolved elements during that time frame (scope) can be disposed of.

Comment: Behind the IView abstraction is eg. windows form Form. Because of Commands that are binded between Presenter and IView (in case of WindowsForms IView implementation - events are used to execute commands). Because of the possibility of memory leak occurrence, i decided to Dispose evey IView explicitly in Presenters just after IView usage ends. In the specific case, I'm not able to use any kind of "Scoping" / Context.

Comment: You have an abstraction of a Service Locator into an Abstract Factory. Your current implementation looks perfectly fine to me. Yes, we should avoid using the IoC-container as a service locator, but, there are cases when it makes sense. I think this is one of them, where the lifetime of the dependency is conceptually shorter than the lifetime of the consumer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer in the post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17436520/4777147
It seems, that solution may be to spawn a view using "new" in the factory.

Unfortunately, in order to use generic factory, every view has to have default constructor. Otherwise you'll need specialized factories for every view.